# Drawing image using Blur effects in UWP is not properly set size for the image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, win2d

I want to blur the image using slider. For this, I have used Win2D Blur effects and draw the image in CanvasControl and added the canvas over the actual image.

Download sample [here](https://github.com/bharathirajauk/MySamples/blob/master/FilterUWP.zip)

Steps.
1. Added CanvasControl in button click. It will add a child to grid over the actual element
2. Change Slider to apply the blur
3. Issue: Image stretched and it's size too large and look like cropped. Not in the given size (500, 400)

**[XAML]**

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="imageGrid">
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="Flower1.jpg" Width="500" Height="400"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">

            <Button Content="AddCanvas" Width="100" x:Name="addCanvas"
                        Click="AddCanvas_Click"/>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Blur" Width="100"/>
                <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="5" Width="200"
                        ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**[C#]**

```
        bool isBlurred;
        GaussianBlurEffect blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
        CanvasControl canv = new CanvasControl();
        CanvasBitmap cbi;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void AddCanvas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            canv.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            canv.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            canv.Draw += Canv_Draw;
            canv.CreateResources += Canv_CreateResources;
            canv.Height = 400;
            canv.Width = 500;

            imageGrid.Children.Add(canv);
        }

        private void Canv_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
        {
            args.DrawingSession.Units = CanvasUnits.Pixels;
            if (isBlurred)
            {
                args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(blur, new Rect(0, 0, 500, 400), new Rect(0, 0, 500, 400));
            }
        }

        private void Canv_CreateResources(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
        {
            args.TrackAsyncAction(CreateResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
        }
        async Task CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasControl sender)
        {
            cbi = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Flower1.jpg");
        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            isBlurred = true;
            blur.Source = cbi;
            blur.BlurAmount = (float)e.NewValue;
            canv.Invalidate();
        }
```

[image]

[image]
I would like to apply the Blur effects to the Image using slider dynamically. But i don't want to change the Actual image to Blur. So, I used Canvas over the Actual image and draw with Blur effect.

Regards,

Bharathi.

Comment: Does the Update2 work ?

Answer (score 1):

> Drawing image using Blur effects in UWP is not properly set size for the image

The problem is that the size of `CanvasControl` is not suit for image source (Image: 960*640 CanvasControl:500*400). If you want to make CanvasControl could display the full image, please set available dpi when call `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync` method. For my testing 185 is suit for your scenario.

```
async Task CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasControl sender)
{
    cbi = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Flower1.jpg",185);

}
```

**Update**

```
//var dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
var display = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
// calculate your monitor's dpi
var dpi = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(display.ScreenWidthInRawPixels, 2) + Math.Pow(display.ScreenHeightInRawPixels, 2)) / display.DiagonalSizeInInches;
// get the CanvasControl inch 
var inch = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(500, 2) + Math.Pow(400, 2)) / dpi;
// calculate last dpi with the image size
var lastdpi = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(960, 2) + Math.Pow(640, 2)) / inch;
```

**Update 1**

If could also set `CanvasControl` size with image size that could avoid to calculate Dpi.

**Update 2**

And you could also resize your image to suit for CanvasControl, Please refer the following  code.

```
public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> ResizeImage(StorageFile file, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memStream);
    }
    IRandomAccessStream imageStream = memStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    if (decoder.PixelHeight > reqHeight || decoder.PixelWidth > reqWidth)
    {
        using (imageStream)
        {
            var resizedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(resizedStream, decoder);
            double widthRatio = (double)reqWidth / decoder.PixelWidth;
            double heightRatio = (double)reqHeight / decoder.PixelHeight;

            double scaleRatio = Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio);

            if (reqWidth == 0)
                scaleRatio = heightRatio;

            if (reqHeight == 0)
                scaleRatio = widthRatio;

            uint aspectHeight = (uint)Math.Floor(decoder.PixelHeight * scaleRatio);
            uint aspectWidth = (uint)Math.Floor(decoder.PixelWidth * scaleRatio);

            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear;

            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = aspectHeight;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = aspectWidth;

            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            return resizedStream;
        }
    }
    return imageStream;
}
```

**Usage**

```
async Task CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasControl sender)
{
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Flower1.jpg")); 
    cbi = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, await ResizeImage(file, 500, 400));    
}
```

Comment: Thanks to provide solution. If i set 185, it is working fine. But, I will upload different size of image. So, I cant determine size of the Image. Please let me, how to calculate dpi value generically. I used below line. but it is not working. returns dpi value as 13.99 in my system. Please advise me on this.                                                                                      var dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().DiagonalSizeInInches;                      
            cbi = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Flower1.jpg", (float)dpi);

Comment: And, This will be used in different system. So I need to calculate dpi value based on the specific system

Comment: @Bharathi, And you could also resize your image to suit for CanvasControl

Comment: I tried both dpi and lastdpi value but it is not working in my machine. if i used 184.5 it is working perfectly for the height (500,400). Please let me know what i did mistake on this.                                                                                       cbi = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Flower1.jpg", (float)lastdpi);

Comment: Now, I removed static size (500, 400) and set size from Image SizeChanged event. This is the real time scenario. Please download the sample from the below link.  https://github.com/bharathirajauk/MySamples/blob/master/FilterUWP_Mod.zip

Comment: Yep, it make sense that set CanvasControl size with the source image size

Comment: But, Still it has problem while drawing in canvas.. Can you please check above sample?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198221/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-bharathi).

Comment: Please check update 2 that resize your image to suit for CanvasControl and you could make static CanvasControl size.

Comment: I simplify a part of code please refer the latest edit.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tried your code but in my case it is not working. I tried your calculation to find out dpi value. But in my screen resolution it not working. So i tried another way to set the DPI. Please check the sample. It is also not working. Could you suggest me how to change the bitmap dpi based on the screen DPI? Sample : https://github.com/SanthiyaArulsamy/Win2DSample/tree/master/FilterUWP_Mod

Comment: For  above case please check update 2  that resize image to suit  for `CanvasControl` and it works.