# How to scale a CanvasBitmap to desired new Width and height in win2d without getting blured Image?

Tags: uwp-xaml, win2d

I have a CanvasBitmap with pixels width and height (1920 x 1080).And i want to scale this canvasBitmap to desired new width and height .For example(1920 x 1080) to (1000 x 560).How can I scale it without getting blured Image?

Answer (score 0):

Fore resize image you could refer [this case reply's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572464/drawing-image-using-blur-effects-in-uwp-is-not-properly-set-size-for-the-image/57575168#57575168) resize method that use `BitmapEncoder` to resize image and then call `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync` reload stream again.

Comment: But this takes more time to process...Is there any other way?What about CanvasDrawingSession.Transform property in win2d?Is this may used to scale?

Comment: I have not tested `CanvasDrawingSession.Transform`, For my experience, above way could used to resize image.

Comment: Can You please Check it out?How to transform?I don't know how to do that!!

Comment: Do you use `CanvasDrawingSession` to draw image?

Comment: yes.I'm using CanvasDrawingSession to draw the CanvasBitmap.